# How to exclude package: results from stack

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to only see lines from my own classes in the stack, when running flutter in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your right, if you're talking about printing lines from `print()` method, you can use

```
flutter logs
```

And if you want to see all the class, you will have to use Logcat, and filter your class there.

Comment: hi, maybe I wasn't clear in my description. the usual flutter run command shows a stack (for errors) including lines from external packages. this makes it hard for me to see where the problem actually ocurred - which is always in one of my own classes. i want a way to see only lines from my own classes in the stack

Comment: @DanHorton I don't think as of now there exists any way of seeing it in terminal but you can always go to Logcat to filter things.